# What can I do for an older dog (13 years) who starts barking early in the morning /

Tags: dogs, behavior, senior-pet

I have a 13 year old female Corgi who started barking at 6:00AM but now the time that she barks is getting closer to 5:00AM.  She has to sleep away from us in  my laundry room that I have lined with pee pads because she can not last more than 3-4 hours without having to go to the bathroom.  Does anyone have a solution for the barking?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to figure out why your dog is barking. This might be a variety of reasons - but given what you say about 'toilet' endurance "I want to go out" might be one.

But so might be activity outside, like the milkman, bin lorries, a cat being 'let out', sunrise, etc. You need to figure out that stimulus before you have any hope of stopping the barking.

I will suggest that lining the whole room with pee pads isn't necessarily doing a lot of good - you're teaching your dog that indoors is 'ok' to toilet. I know it's not so easy to deal with, but perhaps setting aside a sort of 'litter tray' might be a good move. (E.g. as you might with a puppy).

Comment: If not a litter tray then possibly just a small confined area which is the toilet zone.